# How to get rid of cookies notification in chrome browser using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to ask you to help me solve this problem. I want to open chrome window with Selenium, using Java language. Next I would like to find element of input and put some text there. Problem is, that I cannot get rid of cookies notification, because window always opens with me unlogged from google account. How can I open chrome window already logged into my account? Or how can I get rid of google cookies notification?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are often showed up as alerts so this may work:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);//create WebDriverWait
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());//Wait for the alert
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();//accept the alert
```

Comment: not working :/ still pops up window with cookies notification